# Can't access 127.0.0.1 from my Android phone (for LearningWithTexts)

Tags: android, localhost

I'm not a coding genius I just started with these things, but I've set up my own localhost for LWT (the language learning program) and I can't access 127.0.0.1 off of my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone. I just want to be able to read the texts and use it just like I do on my laptop. I tried everything with the my IP and the 10.0.2.2 thing but it get's stuck on it and doesn't do anything. 
Edit: I also tried with my IP address but it just gets stuck.

Comment: If your phone and system connected to the same network. Try to get the IP address of your system and instead of local host use that IP and will work.

Comment: For accessing the localhost, you need to provide the IP address. Try connecting with IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to same network, in laptop write ipconfig to get its ipV4 address. Then try turn off your firewall for some time in your laptop and in laptop "allow remote access to your computer. When every thing is fine,for permanently allow this, you can add Inbound and outbound rules to allow a program in any protocol (http, tcp,udp) any port from "Windows defender firewall with advance security".